# Why is sort working for structure but not for int vector

Tags: c++, templates

I read an article in geekforgeeks for sorting in a particular order (vector).
This is the code that I got from the site.

[image]

You can see the output is correct below in the image.
This is my code now

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a < b);
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    cout<<"Current size is "<<v.size()<<"\nPutting elements now\n";     
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
        v.push_back(rand()%1000);                                            
    //sort(v.begin(),v.end(),greater<int>());                                
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),max);
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) 
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
     return 0;
}
```

I get this error

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     sort(v.begin(),v.end(),max);
```

**`PS: I know about using greater <int> ()`**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7359094) are discouraged. Please provide the code as text directly in the question.

Comment: With `using namespace std;` the name `max` might mean your `::max` or `std::max`.

Comment: This is why you should never use `using namespace std`